# login Facebook via perl?

Tags: perl, facebook

Is there a script to login Facebook via perl?
I search many perl scripts and test them, but all fail.
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "to login Facebook"?  OAuth for an application being built on the platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to login to Facebook. You probably want to use the Facebook API to access various features of Facebook. CPAN seems to have [a number of modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=facebook) for doing this. I haven't used any of them so I have no opinion of their quality.

Comment: +1 (and I'd be surprised if Facebook terms of service allowed bots which logged on to the HTML interface).

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/~rizen/Facebook-Graph-1.0300/lib/Facebook/Graph.pm) is the one you'll want to use if you're starting out new work now.  JT Smith gave a presentation on this module at YAPC::NA::2011 in Asheville in June -- looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Its a 3 steps process 1st you need to create a URL having fb_app_id and all permission and response type should be code and also valid oauth redirect.. Then redirect this page in browser(using JS in my case). Once user logged in fb will redirect to specific locations (you mentioned in oauth redirect) with some temp code. This temp code will have 2hrs of life time(may be little more). Exchange temp code to access_token by using  oauth/access_token passing app id /secret and temp code. In this way you can authenticate the users to your tool.

Thanks 
Amit